# Add scala-async to library dependency but still get "not found: value async" error

Tags: scala, maven, asynchronous, intellij-idea

I have a simple function using "async":

```
def delay(t: Duration): Future[Unit] = async {
    blocking {
        Thread.sleep(t.toMillis)
    }
}
```

I've added the following jar to my project through Project Settings / Libraries (from Maven) :

```
SBT: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-async_2.11:0.9.2:jar
```

and also found this dependency already in the "build.sbt":

```
projectDetailsMap := {

  val depsNode = Seq(
    .......
    "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-async" % "0.9.2"
  )}
```

But when I rebuilt the project, even restarted Intellij and rebuilt again, I still got this error:

```
Error:(65, 44) not found: value async
    def delay(t: Duration): Future[Unit] = async {
                                           ^
```

Can someone tell me what might be wrong? Thanks a lot!

I'm using scala "2.11.5" on Mac

Comment: Did you import it? `import scala.async.Async.{async, await}`

Comment: Yes Kolmar, I imported it, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I reinstalled my Intellij IDEA, changed the default JDK 1.6 in "idea.properties" to my current JDK 1.8, and also imported my project again as an SBT project. Problem solved. It might be caused by some conflicts in my environment.